# Red-Black Tree derived from TreeMap

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, treemap

I am currently working on a program where I am to create a red-black tree class that is derived from the pre-existing TreeMap, and I am running into problems due to not fully understanding what I am supposed to be doing.

This class can only support the following methods:

```
public boolean is Empty()
public void makeEmpty()
public void insert(Comparable x)
public void delete(Comparable x)
public void deleteMin()
public void deleteMax()
public Object find(Comparable x)
public Object findMin() 
public Object findMax()
```

I'm supposed to use TreeMap objects inside of the class, and I'm not totally sure if I'm on the right track.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class RBTree {

    private TreeMap myMap = new TreeMap();

    public RBTree() {   
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return myMap.isEmpty();
    }   
    public void makeEmpty(){
        myMap.clear();
    }
```

Am I on the right track? If I'm not, can you help me get on track? Thanks!

EDIT: slightly changed isEmpty and added makeEmpty. Now I'm stuck on insert/delete, I think the Comparable parameter is throwing me off.

Comment: You're on the right track.

Comment: Do you fully understand what a [red-black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) tree is? Don't dive into code until you do.

Comment: @bejado Why not? He's just delegating to `TreeMap`.

Comment: @bejado I have a pretty good idea of what a red-black tree is